# Is there such a thing as a finite dimensional left shift operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My linear algebra assignment presents the left shift operator as

$\phi : \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}, \phi(a_1,a_2,...,) = (a_2,a_3,...)$

Does $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ here mean that this operator can take in vectors of any natural valued dimension? I struggle to understand how it would do that since the last entry would be undefined. Intuitively I thought we should have $\mathbb{R}^\infty \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\infty$ instead. Am I missing something?

Comment: But there is no last entry...

Comment: We have $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} = \{ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \}$ which is the space of all sequences formed of elements in the reals, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Jonathan Hole I just understood the meaning of the comma just before the closed bracket. That answers my question, cheers!